# Spring boot modify model.atrribute value defined in one controller from another controller

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the following controller that renders an HTML view. Inside this controller, I have defined a `model.attribute("bill", bill);` , which renders the default value of `0` on the view. The controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model model, Product product) {

        //not relevant code above

        String bill = "0";
        model.addAttribute("bill", bill);
```

I have another controller in different class that I want to update the value of bill and redirect me to the same page. My attempt to achieve this ended in producing this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/products/checkout", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getBill(@RequestParam("checkout") String order, @RequestParam("bill") String bill, @ModelAttribute Model model) {

    String finalBill = "124pounds";
    model.addAttribute("bill", finalBill);
```

And the view looks like this:

```
<form th:action="@{/products/checkout}" method="post">
    <h3> Please type your order:</h3>
        <input type="text" th:name= "checkout" id="checkout" placeholder="banana,apple,tomato (separated with commas)"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Checkout">
        <h3>Your bill is :<span th:name="bill" th:text="' '+${bill}+' c'"></span></h3>
        </form>
```

What I want to achieve is to make the second controller called `getBill()` to update the value of bill and redirect to the same page. I got lost a bit and I am not sure how to achieve the desired functionality.

**Note:** `String bill = "0";` **and** `String finalBill = "124pounds";` **are just there to test if the value is changing when the `Checkout` button is pressed.** The error I am getting looks like this.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required String parameter 'bill' is not present
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'bill' is not present
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
```

What happens now is that the default `0` value is shown, but when I click the `Checkout` I get the error above. Basically I want to update the value from the `getBill()` and return the same view, which I am not sure is possible ?!

Comment: In your HTML, there is no input with the name bill therefore, it is not being sent to your controller. That is why you get the error. I recommend  creating a form class and using th:object + th:field in your forms though.

Comment: I actually fixed it, but now I am getting `No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.ui.Model`. Do you have any idea how I can send to my view a plain String?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to only change the value o bill, and then return to the same html file, which is the one with the form. If that is correct, then all you need to do is remove the `@ModelAttribute` from `getBill()` and add the order string to the model.

it would look something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/products/checkout", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getBill(@RequestParam("checkout") String order, @RequestParam("bill") String bill, Model model) {

String finalBill = "124pounds";
model.addAttribute("bill", finalBill);
model.addAttribute("checkout", order);
return "yourview";
```